# Replace the current workbook with another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Workbooks, **WB1** and **WB2**.

My colleagues have copy of **WB1** on their desktop that has a data connection to our local network server, which is connected to multiple workbooks using PowerQuery.

I constantly update **WB2** for data reporting, which will be shared with my colleagues upon approval of management as **WB1**.

When I share the updated version of **WB2** I rename it and send it via email as `WB1.v05`. Most of the time my colleagues forget or overlook the updated version sent via email, which leads to having their report in the old version.

I have a specific cell value in **WB2** where I keep the version number of **WB2** (i.e. Sheet1 Cell `A1 = v.02`).

I want a VBA script in **WB1** that will check if their copy has the latest version of **WB2** and, if not, then make a copy of **WB2** and rename and copy it (i.e., to `WB1.v06`) in the same location where **WB1** is saved on their computer. After that, it should delete the old versions.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database instead of Excel.

Comment: Why not consider making a macro for outlook and send it to all your colleagues. Every time they run the macro, it will fetch your email, take your attachment and replace the old file with your new one.

Comment: I wish I could do macros in Outlook.  Yes, we did have a database and I am extracting the dataset from it but several data transformation is needed thanks to PowerQuery then load it in data model then make a PowerPivot for dashboard reports. That is why making this excel updates all the copies of each user via VBA if even possible will be ideal for me, but if not then I just needed to informed and remind the end user for new versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution but it works.  This assumes that the sheets in WB1 and WB2 are exactly the same except for the data that you change.  In the if statement you point the .cells(1,2) to the cell that contains your version reference. All you need to do is create a button in the workbooks that launches this sub.

```
Sub UpdateWorkBook()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Dim wb1sht As Worksheet
Dim wb2sht As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Workbooks.Open ("<<<~~ Path to WB2 ~~>>>")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("WB2")

Set wb1sht = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wb2sht = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

If wb1sht.Cells(1, 2).Value <> wb2sht.Cells(1, 2).Value Then
    wb2sht.Cells.Copy Destination:=wb1sht.Cells

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have to inform the User to click this button to tigger the Macro. Thanks,  appreciate your help.